# Accidentally installed python 3.5 vs. python3.5 : Is this bad?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux-mint

I run Linux Mint with Python 3.4.x pre-installed. I'm starting a new project and wanted to take advantage of 3.5ish stuff so I decided I would install 3.5 and create my new virtual environment pointing to it.

So, I by accident typed

```
sudo apt-get install python 3.5
```

Which I've since learned is different from

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5.
```

I know that is different because the later requires adding a new repository wherein the former I was able to do before I added the deadsnakes repo.

So, I went through the install of "python 3.5" - it asked me some questions about FTP to ined(something) or standalone, then I installed python3.5.

My question(s) is

1) What is python 3.5? (with the space), 
2) Did I break anything, 
3) Should I uninstall python 3.5 even though the uninstall warns me not to unless I really know what I am doing?

Thank you

Comment: 3.6 came out today. Why not just forget about "python 3.5" vs "python3.5" and install 3.6?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 *"Python3.6 is worthy of being called Python3"* -- Raymond Hettinger

Comment: @TigerhawkT3; Thank you, that is good advice and I will do that. However, the question still remains as to what I accidentally installed and weather I broke anything.

Comment: using `sudo apt-get install python 3.5` you probably install Python 2 but you should have it already (I use Linux Mint 17 and I have installed Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and even 2.4)

Comment: BTW: there was [unofficial repo with precompiled Python 2.3-3.5 for Ubuntu and Mint](https://launchpad.net/%7Efkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75) but it seems author has no time to compile new versions.

Comment: On Mint 17 you shouldn't uninstall Python 2 because system uses it. I don't know what with the newest MInt - because it based on Ubuntu and the newest Ubuntu uses 3.5 in system and doesn't need 2.x

Comment: @TigerhawkT3; Now that I look at it, I guess the reason that I don't install 3.6 is that I don't see a repo for 3.6 that lets me use apt-get, and I'm chicken to try to install from source.

Comment: this should be on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions always have newer patches and fixes. Python 3.5.2 is probably what you installed if you used `sudo apt-get install python3.5`. There is also Python 3.6 now.

With the space (`sudo apt-get install python 3.5`) it would mean install `python` and `3.5` so maybe it just installed/updated python2.

Anyway, having multiple versions is not an issue. You may alias each install and use them as required.

#### Should I uninstall python 3.5 even though the uninstall warns me not to unless I really know what I am doing?

You shall do that if no other program/dependency is lost. Have you used it in some code? (which wouldn't work if its gone!) If you haven't then go ahead uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that the space meant two different applications. I feel better now.

Comment: It turns out that "...apt-get install 3.5" actually tries to install some stuff, now I am worried again.

Comment: @SteveJ check `/var/log/apt/term.log`

Answer (score 0):

It's not good. I had the same installing Ruby and accidentally typing:

***Don't do this!!***

```
apt install ruby 2.4
```

It installed the latest Ruby and many gigabytes of packages with 2.4 in the name.

I tried to remove them with

```
apt remove 2.4
```

...but it turns out some of these packages are essential for the Operating System.

To list the packages with label 2.4:

```
apt-cache show 2.4
```

So uninstalling non-essential packages could be an option if you manage to list them and use that output as arguments for apt remove. But I suppose even then your system may potentially be left unstable.

Luckily I ran the command on a relatively fresh Raspbian install so I'll just do a clean install. Apt install is a surprisingly dangerous command, :D, good luck