# What does apt-get install 3.5 do?

Tags: python, package-managers, linux-mint

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310671/accidentally-installed-python-3-5-vs-python3-5-is-this-bad) about accidentally calling `apt-get install python 3.5`(space intentional) on Linux Mint. I learned, or was reminded that it was the same as calling `...install python`, then calling `...install 3.5`.

My new question is this:

I have python 3.5 installed on my Linux Mint system, via `apt-get install python3.5`

If I type `apt-get install 3.5`, it seems like a shorthand for python 3.5, because I get a list of already installed packages that have the python 3.5 name in them.

However, I also get a list of NEW packages;

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
blt idle-python3.5 libpython3.5 libpython3.5-dbg libpython3.5-dev
libpython3.5-gdbm libpython3.5-gdbm-dbg libpython3.5-testsuite
libpython3.5-tk libpython3.5-tk-dbg python3.5-complete python3.5-dbg
python3.5-dev python3.5-doc python3.5-examples python3.5-gdbm
python3.5-gdbm-dbg python3.5-tk python3.5-tk-dbg python3.5-venv
```

So why if I have python 3.5 installed does 
typing `install 3.5`show new packages wherein typing `install python3.5` does not? What is the relationthip between python3.5 and 3.5, and what (if any) deleterious affect does installing just 3.5 have?

Comment: `install 3.5` installs all packages with `3.5`, not only `Python 3.5`. As I saw the newest Ubuntu install `python3.5` without `tkinter` (`python3.5-tk`). And I'm sure `python3.5` doesn't install `python3.5-dev` which have C/C++ files .h to compile some modules for Python.

Comment: @furas By all packages, do you mean any package in any subscribed library that as "3.5" in it?

Comment: yes all packages with 3.5 in name (and maybe in description too).

Comment: That seems less than good.

Comment: is your system working slower ? if not then there is no problem. Don't repair it because you brake something else :)

Comment: this should be on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

When you use command `apt-get install 3.5` or (in my case)`sudo apt-get install 3.5`, system checks for all packages with 3.5 in their name.

It basically uses a **regex** to find all packages(not only Python packages) that match the *pattern* `3.5`

Same can be seen in the screenshot I have attached: [image: Regex search for apt-get install command]